# Android File Transfer continuously fails to copy files to the SD card over USB in Android Lollipop

Tags: android

Android File Transfer fails to copy showing the following message:

[image: could not copy the file error screenshot]

Another symptom is that the copy is not continuous. It freezes after copying a few megabytes during a couple of seconds.

I also have tried using [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid). It transfers data over WiFi instead USB. Google Chrome freezes after a few seconds even turning on "remote transfer" option to "always" in the AirDroid configuration

I also have tried [SHAREit](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/shareit-connect-transfer/id1040029915?mt=12) changing the path to receive files [to the SD Card](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n8rEDA6P2rk). It gets stuck without sending anything or giving any feedback.

I have Android Lollipop 5.0.1 on a Samsung Galaxy S4. The only options available are MTP and PTP (camera).

The question is: what is the problem? Why can't I copy the files?

Comment: It seems simply corrupted...

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: @patrix I have added the question. I wrongly though it was implicit in the explanation. The question is: what is the problem? Why can't I copy the files?

Comment: Is it an ancient, slow SD card? When did you last format it, clean and new? SDFormatter: https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/

Answer (score 1):

Try using SmartFinder for Android. It's on the App Store and it's free. Make sure you have USB debugging enabled before using SmartFinder though.
**How to enable USB debugging?**
Go to your smartphone's **Settings -> About device -> Tap on the Build number until you get a message "You are now a developer!"**
Go back to the main page of **Settings ->Developer options -> make sure USB debugging is ticked.**
Once you connect your phone for the first time, it'll install an app called **SmartFinder** (about 4 MB) on your phone. It won't have an icon, no need to launch it.
Then, simply find the .mp3 file under **Music** in SmartFinder, select it and tap **Import**.
If that doesn't work, then the file might be corrupt.

Comment: It also get stucks when I tried to format it performing the long formatting way (I received the component to format it yesterday). I did it from VirtualBox with Windows as I did not find a proper way to format it well in OSX. I think corrupted. It just I got the last 3 memories corrupted, so it invites me to think maybe it is my problem!

Comment: @chelder Yup. Probably corrupt. Do the files work on your phone?

Comment: Around the first 8 Gb of files work well. The following files don't. The same in both SD cards. Now I'm trying this tool specific to format SD Cards: https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/eula_mac/index.html

Comment: @chelder If some files work, then it probably isn't the SD Card's problem, but the file's.

Comment: Everything is copied without errors. Then: ¡surprise! 10Gb are OK. The rest of the folders are simply empty. It seems a fraud of SD cards that seem 64GB but are actually 10GB..

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same issue - however, it turned out to be a permission problem, so I just changed the permissions from read-only to read-write.

Answer (score 0):

For me, rebooting the Android device did the trick. However, it is not a permanent solution - it stops working again until I reboot it.